# Selecting pandas dataframe columns whose names are like strings in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a pandas DataFrame, `df`, as shown below and a list, `l`, also shown below. I want to select the columns from `df` for which any of the column names start with the strings in `l`. So in this case I want to get `df[['word', 'hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3']]`. Is there a quick way I can do this? I could loop through each element of the list but that could take a lot of time for larger DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'word': [13,4],
    'another': [1,4],
    'champ': [1,5],
    'hello1': [1,2],
    'hello2': [4,5],
    'hello3': [7,8]
})

l = ['word', 'hello']

#what I want to get:
   word  hello1 hello2  hello3
0   13      1      4    7
1   4       2      5    8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the column starting with given words, you can do:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.match(f'^({"|".join(l)})')]
```

Output:

```
   word  hello1  hello2  hello3
0    13       1       4       7
1     4       2       5       8
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.startswith(tuple(l))]
```